# CMD- How To Ping A Local Web server?

Tags: tomcat, cmd, webserver, local, ping

I am trying to make a batch file to ping my local web server and check wither its up or not
we have a tomcat web server its port is 8080.

- when I try to ping `00.00.00.00:8080` it give me could not find local host
- and when I try to ping `00.00.00.00:8080` it give me bad parameter
  and I cant use the www ping cause its local

I have even tried telnet but telnet need interaction to check for the web server status
and I need it to be automatic cause I will edit it to send mails with the server status.

Comment: You're asking wrong question. `ping` uses ICMP protocol with a specific port, it makes as much sense `pinging` web server as FTP one. Use `curl` or `wget` instead, or, even better, switch for specific tools for this very case.

Comment: will you please instruct me more about the curl and wget commands ,, like give me an example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I Used The `Nmap` command You should download and install it 1st from http://nmap.org

> nmap -p8080 IPaddress

Answer (score 2):

why you are pinging 00.00.00.00 ??

try this

`ping localhost`

Comment: i use the IP for the machine that have the web server on it cause i am trying to ping from a different machine on the network

Comment: from my experience any web server won't use `00.00.00.00` ip address. And it gives error may be because webserver won't allow other ip to access files. You have to change that rule of allow and Deny ip.